# Sharing Rules for Knowledge in Salesforce

Tags: salesforcedx, sharing-rule, public-group, lightning-knowledge

Is it possible to create sharing rules for Knowledge? How can I share knowledge record with Role/Public Groups?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, as of the Summer 20 release, Sharing for Knowledge is available as a beta feature!
https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer20/release-notes/rn_knowledge_sharing.htm
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_sharing.htm&type=5

There are some limitations though so would be good to review the considerations here.
https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=knowledge_sharing_considerations.htm&type=5

EDIT:

Sharing for Knowledge is Generally Available as of the Winter 21 release.  https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/winter21/release-notes/rn_knowledge_sharing_enhancements.htm?edition=&impact=